# Capture web-page as a photo and attach it into a email form

Tags: php, jquery, email, send, capture

I've been looking on how to make this, found several topics here at stackoverlow, but is nothing similar to what I need. So, I have a web-page: http://creditbay.com/calculator/ , which contains a form with inputs. I'd like to add a button that generate a screenshot (PNG or JPG, doesn't matter) of what the user has been typed in the inputs and open a email form with this screenshot attached, so the user can only add his e-mail (or someone elses' email) and hit "Send".

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why must it be a screenshot? Why not just use the contents of the text fields? The only case I see capturing a webpage as useful is if you are using thumbnails for changing themes in a CMS or for displaying webdesigns in any matter... Information is information and can be displayed in a 1000 ways, a design in only 1

Comment: Besides, you make it impossible to copy any of the information provided then later on

Comment: Because I have 46 web-pages and want to avoid doing manually scripts for each web-page.

Comment: well, you should be able to copy paste that code too. Just read out the forms with js and send an e-mail with php. Copy that code to all your sites. The only things you need to change for each site, is the names (ids) of the inputs.

Comment: I told that to my client, but he is stubborn as hell and wanted a PDF generated of the webpage attached in an email. I was able to convince him for an image.

Comment: [Do not agree to things you don't want to do.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfxTc7_1UVE)

Comment: So there's no way I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

So there's no way I can achieve what I want? I thought it will be easy to be done with html2canvas and then attach the image in a simple email form?